# Access our own AWS/RDS instance from cloudcontrol apps

Tags: cloudcontrol

I would like to use our own RDS instances with apps hosted with cloudcontrol.
I know this is possible because all i need is EC2 security group info and account number for cloud control.

However, there is no mention of direct use of Amazon RDS instances in cloudcontrol documentation.

Has anyone used their own RDS instances with Cloudcontrol apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is of course possible. We recommend to start the RDS instance in the EU region to be close to our EC2 instances.

Here's the account information you need to setup the RDS security group to allow access from our machines.

AWS Account ID: 481137082768
EC2 Security Group: lxc

Comment: Thank you... looking forward to test drive cloudControl!